# Use an array of pointer in a class

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

I'd like to use an array (very large) of pointer in a class:

```
char* myClass::_myArray[1200000];   // 1.2 million elements
```

If I new it in my constructor:

```
myClass::myClass()
{
   for (int n = 0; n < 1200000; n++)
   {
      _myArray[n] = new char[32];          
   }
}
```

then in my destructor, I dispose it:

```
myClass::~myClass()
{
   for (int n = 0; n < 1200000; n++)
   {
      if (NULL != _myArray[n])
      {
          delete[] _myArray[n];  // exception throws here
          _myArray[n] = NULL;
      }
   }
}
```

it always throw exception like following picture:

[image]

I have no idea why. I am wondering if I would like to pre-allocate a buffer for the class object until it quits, how should I do this? This buffer should work like a global variable, that can be used any time the function/methods within the class is called.

Thanks a lot. Appreciate any opinion and education.

**Additional information:**

I set the array size 1000 (`char* myClass::_myArray[1000];` ), it works fine. When I set it to 5000, it throws exception like this after the app exit. When it is 1.2 million, the exception throws when app starts.

the `delete[] _myArray[n]` is where the exception happens, but it happens at random `n` number.

Comment: What is the value of n when the assertions fails?

Comment: Note that deleting a null pointer is safe to do in C++ - you do not have to check if the pointer is null before deleting it. But of course you should still set the deleted pointer to null afterwards.

Comment: It was strange. Initially it seems like random number. Then after I did some change it seems at 0;

Comment: Show as *all your code*.

Comment: Try setting array size smaller and see whether issue remains or not.

Comment: I set the array size 1000, it works fine. When I set it to 5000, it throws exception like this after the app exit. When it is 1.2 million, the exception throws when app starts.

Comment: What is the code you posted? Where in that code is this array of pointers? Probably you can delete most of the code in that file (including _all_ the commented-out code) and still the exception would occur. When there is nothing left that you can delete without "fixing" the exception, post that instead of the big file, and maybe someone can see where the problem is. Right now we have to look for a small problem in a big pile of not-problem code.

Comment: just use delete instead of delete[]

Comment: @purpletech Seems it does not work. Still throw the same exception.

Comment: can you print n and see when it does that ?

Comment: @purpletech it seems pretty random number of n. See my "additional information" in the original thread.

Comment: Its best to check if _myArray[n] really go the memory so adding if ( _myArray[n] == NULL ) cout << "ERROR : NO memory"; will help after the new in constructor , also memset( _myArray[n] to 0 after you get the memory

Comment: I added your checking code, and I put a break point at cout << "ERROR : NO memory"; , but it seems it never hits there, which I think is good.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you are running out of memory, and overwriting something.  Try experimenting more to find the exact size the errors occur.

Comment: @purpletech, delete on NULL shouldn't be a problem unless it has been redefined...

Comment: @JamesCurran OK. But 1.2 million bytes is only 1.2 MB....I think?

Comment: How many instances of your class do you have? Only destroying your class once? Nothing else going on concurrently? No other _funny_ business?  I just ran the code you show and nothing happened (OS X with clang, however).

Comment: @Kaiged Should I post all my code here? Or how to share with you guys?

Comment: @Ono Just run the program with only the code you have posted. Don't share all of the code, only the minimum to reproduce the problem. I think the problem might lie elsewhere.

Comment: @Kaiged I think you are right. It is probably somewhere else. It is just showing it is happening at the delete. Thanks!

Comment: @Ono: But _myArray isn't an array of 1.2 million chars, but 1.2m char*, which are usually 4 bytes, so 4.8 MB.

Comment: @JamesCurran Right. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `delete[]` on a single pointer instead of just `delete`:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 1200000; n++)
{
  if (NULL != _myArray[n])
  {
      delete _myArray[n];
      _myArray[n] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could just call `delete[]` on the array itself:

```
delete[] _myArray;
```

This should be safe because you are using this in a destructor and _myArray is going out of scope with your object and therefore none of the pointers with now invalid objects are going to be available once this instance of the class goes away. If that is not the

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/ for reference

Comment: I thought I used delete[] because each _myArray[n] is created by new[]? It is an array.

Comment: So it is, my poor reading. I'll look at a little closer and get back

Comment: @Ono I'm attempting to recreate your bug, but with the code you've provided, and implementing the simplest class definition possible(see below). I get no errors.  
`class myClass`  
`{`  
`public:`  
`myClass();`  
`~myClass();`  
`char* _myArray[1200000];`  
`};`  
Can you provide more details about your code?

Comment: @Ono If your program is large and complex and posting your code is prohibitive, then if possible you should update your question with example code that compiles and reproduces your bug. If nothing else it will help you narrow down which part of your code is causing the runtime error.

Comment: Thanks I will keep looking. Like @Kai said, the problem is probably somewhere else. I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (NULL != _myArray[n])
  {
      delete[] _myArray[n];
      _myArray = NULL;
  }
```

You do not want to set `_myArray` to NULL *inside* the loop.  In fact, you *never* want to set `_myArray` to NULL.  If `_myArray` is actually defined as you show here (instead of as `char** myClass::_myArray = new char*[1200000];`) then setting it to NULL should be a compiler error.

Comment: I am sorry, I re-edit the thread. I actually set _myArray[n] = NULL;

Comment: It seems this answer still hints at the problem even with the edit.  `_myArray[n]` is only a `char`, not a `char*`. `_myArray` should be a `char**`

Comment: _myArray[n] is a char*

Comment: @Ono oh so it is. my mistake

Comment: @Kaiged no problem I really appreciate you are trying to help.